# Algorithm to efficiently find horizontal visibility graph (HVG)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Given a series of numbers, represented by vertices, let two vertices, i and j, be connected only if i,j>k for all k between i and j. This graph is called the HVG of the series. In other words, if the bars can "see" each other when plotted like such (ignore the numbers at the bottom): [image]

I'm trying to come up with an efficient algorithm for determining the adjacency matrix of the HVG for a given series.

The algorithm I've currently come up with just uses three for loops, all nested. The outermost loop iterates over all values (placing them in `i`), then a loop within that iterates over all values that come after `i` (placing them in `j`), and then a loop within that which iterates over all values between `i` and `j` (placing them in `k`). Then if the k'th element is greater than either the i'th element or the j'th element, then `i` and `j` are not connected, so it moves onto checking the next value of `j`.

But I feel like there must exist a solution which is more efficient than using three nested loops. I know that if `j>i` we no longer need to check for any more vertices connected to `i` (because for all subsequent values of `j`, there exists a number between `i` and `j` that's greater than `i`)... but unfortunately this alone still gives that a lot of vertices are connected when they shouldn't be.

Is there a better way than my current loop-happy method?

Comment: Somewhat similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833986/number-of-subarrays-with-range-less-than-k

Answer (score 4):

Moving from left to right, maintain a stack of all bars that could be seen by bars to the right of your current position.  The height of bars on the stack will always be decreasing from left to right.

When you encounter a new bar, it can see and be seen by all the bars on the stack with height less than the new height, plus one more.  Mark these edges in your visibility graph.  Then remove all bars with height less than or equal to the new bar (because they can't be seen anymore by bars to the right) and add the new bar.

Total time is O(N), not counting the O(N^2) time to initialize your adjacency matrix with zeros.